# weird results when execute 2 or more queries in one sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing MySQL queries using temporary tables

here is the queries :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (
SELECT closedcash.HOSTSEQUENCE ,tickets.TICKETID , 
RECEIPTS.DATENEW,PAYMENTS.PAYMENT, PAYMENTS.NOTES, PAYMENTS.TOTAL 

FROM PAYMENTS,RECEIPTS,closedcash,tickets

where CLOSEDCASH.MONEY = RECEIPTS.MONEY AND PAYMENTS.RECEIPT = RECEIPTS.ID 
and closedcash.HOSTSEQUENCE=230 and receipts.ID=tickets.ID

ORDER BY RECEIPTS.DATENEW

);


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (
select TICKETID, DATENEW, timestampdiff(SECOND,prevdatenew,DATENEW) as "diff"
from (
    select TICKETID, DATENEW, @prevDateNew as prevdatenew, 
      @prevDateNew := DATENEW
    from t1 order by DATENEW
) t1     
);

UPDATE t2 SET diff =0 ORDER BY DATENEW ASC LIMIT 1;

SELECT
CONCAT(HOUR(t2.DATENEW), ':00-', HOUR(t2.DATENEW)+1, ':00') AS Hours ,
 SEC_TO_TIME( sum(diff) / count(t2.DATENEW) ) 
from t2
group BY CONCAT(HOUR(t2.DATENEW), ':00-', HOUR(t2.DATENEW)+1, ':00') 
order by t2.DATENEW ;
```

when i execute one query at a time one by one not as one file ,it works great , 
 **but when i run all the queries as one file.sql or copy and paste all the queries in phpmyadmin in sql editor it shows null and zeroes "weird results, i dont know why ????**

Here is screenshot of good results when i execute one query at a time :

[image: no error in results when i execute one query at a time]

and Here is screenshot of bad results when i execute all queries from one file :

[image]

Comment: You wrote, " it shows null and zeroes "  What, exactly, shows nulls and zeros?

Comment: Thanks for your replay , i provided 2 images to  figure out what is happening with me ...